# No [programming] questions here!

Tags: discussion, tags

I think we should burniate or rename the [programming](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming) tag.

It has 4 (think about it! Only 4!) questions, all of which have been tagged with other tags.

## Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No. Knowing that a question involves code does not give any more information.

## Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

I think programming is off topic.

## Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

I don’t think so.

## Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

It could mean:

- Programming questions (such as debugging ones) **[off topic!]**
- Programming for an open source project
- How to program **[opinion based]**

Can we burniate it?

Comment: I've edited the tag out.

Comment: Do you want to write an answer, then, so the question can get closed?  I can't think of a more definitive answer than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, and I've edited the tag out of those questions. Thanks!